# Remove namespace entry from element, which was added by XSLT during transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I'm using the xslt file to convert set of xml files, some of the tags in xml are defined in another namespace.

What xslt does is from AddBooks element tag first copy everything, except the bookattach element where attribute bookname = 'AA12' then construct a new element bookattach where bookname="AA12" in all cases and copy into it all the children of bookattach where bookname="AA12" and bookname="A12".

Well the xslt is working as expected but the problem is that when it copies element bookattach where attribute bookname = 'AA12' there its adding the name space entry. For example it copies an entry as:

```
<bookattach xmlns:mynamespace="http://myorg.com/mymodel/Library" bookname="AA12">
<book bookname="bacbook1" description="This is test book1"/>
</bookattach>
```

I do not want to copy this namespace entry in the transformed xml, (my source xml also does not contain namespace entry in bookattach tag),
so how can I get rid of this namespace entry in this specific tag?

My xslt is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:mynamespace="http://myorg.com/mymodel/Library"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:key name="bookbyid" match="mynamespace:bookattach" use="@bookname"/>

    <xsl:template match="mynamespace:AddBooks">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() [ not( (self::mynamespace:bookattach and @bookname = 'AA12') )]"/>
          <bookattach bookname="AA12">
              <xsl:copy-of select="key('bookbyid','AA12')/*"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="key('bookbyid','A12')/*">
                  <xsl:if test="not(./@bookName = key('bookbyid','AA12')/*/@bookName)">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </bookattach>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element to avoid having the namespace declared in your output XML, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:mynamespace="http://myorg.com/mymodel/Library"
            version="1.0"
            exclude-result-prefixes="mynamespace">
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but can  you please tell why does it add the prefixes when they do not exist in source document?

Comment: What do you mean by telling "*they do not exist in source document?*" Can you edit your post and add the input XML you're using?

Comment: @4022ax XSLT _never_ generates prefixes that were not a) present in the input document or b) introduced by you, the author of the stylesheet.

Comment: When you use a literal result element in the stylesheet (like `<bookattach>`) then by default all namespaces that are in scope for that element (i.e. declared on a containing element in the stylesheet) are copied to the result; you can prevent this using exclude-result-prefixes, or by using xsl:element rather than a literal result element.